# JMeter: Trying to verify two or more values in a randomly assigned json path

Tags: json, jmeter

I have a JSON response that looks like this:

```
{
"results": [
    {
        "entityType": "PERSON",
        "id": 679,
        "graphId": "679.PERSON",
        "details": [
            {
                "entityType": "PERSON",
                "id": 679,
                "graphId": "679.PERSON",
                "parentId": 594,
                "role": "Unspecified Person",
                "relatedEntityType": "DOCUMENT",
                "relatedId": 058,
                "relatedGraphId": "058.DOCUMENT",
                "relatedParentId": null
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "entityType": "PERSON",
        "id": 69678,
        "graphId": "69678.PERSON",
        "details": [
            {
                "entityType": "PERSON",
                "id": 678,
                "graphId": "678.PERSON",
                "parentId": 594,
                "role": "UNKNOWN",
                "relatedEntityType": "DOCUMENT",
                "relatedId": 145,
                "relatedGraphId": "145.DOCUMENT",
                "relatedParentId": null
            }
        ]
    }
```

The problem with this JSON response is that $.results[0] is not always the same, and it can have dozens of results. I know I can do individual JSON Assertion calls where I do the JSON with a wild card

$.results[*].details[0].entityType

$.results[*].details[0].relatedEntityType
etc

However I need to verify that both "PERSON" and "DOCUMENT" match correctly in the same path on one api call since the results come back in a different path each time.

Is there a way to do multiple calls in one JSON Assertion or am I using the wrong tool?

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Grav

Answer (score 0):

I don't think JSON Assertion is flexible enough, consider switching to [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) where you have the full flexibility in terms of defining whatever pass/fail criteria you need.

Example code which checks that:

- all attributes values which match `$.results[*].details[0].entityType` query are equal to `PERSON`
- and all attributes values which match `$.results[*].details[0].relatedEntityType` are equal to `DOCUMENT`

would be:

```
def entityTypes = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$.results[*].details[0].entityType').collect().find { !it.equals('PERSON') }
def relatedEntityTypes = com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), '$.results[*].details[0].relatedEntityType').collect().find { !it.equals('DOCUMENT') }

if (entityTypes.size() != 1) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage('Entity type mismatch, one or more entries are not "PERSON" ' + entityTypes)
}
if (relatedEntityTypes.size() != 1) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage('Entity type mismatch, one or more entries are not "DOCUMENT" ' + relatedEntityTypes)
}
```

More information:

1. [SampleResult class JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html)
2. [Groovy: Working with collections](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#List-Filtering)
3. [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial/)